# discord.js бот не реагирует на команды

Tags: javascript, discord

бот в сети на серваке, но все равно на команды никак не реагирует.

```
bot.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log(message.content); // после того как чел напишет в дс серваке сообщение должно это высветиться в терминале , но такого не бывает, не понимаю в чем проблема помогите плез
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала проверьте вашу версию discord.js - `npm ls discord.js` в терминал. В случае, если версия 13+:

1. Укажите нужные "интенты" в начале кода:

```js
const bot = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

2. Ивент `message` был переименован в `messageCreate`:

```js
bot.on("messageCreate", message => { // ... // })
```